# Convert HiddenField datatype from string to int

Tags: c#, asp.net

I used jquery pager to  load data to my gridview . Now i have buttons on every rows of my gridview.On button click i am suppose to get the id value of the first column which is an integer value.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfId" runat="server" />
  <asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                                        BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderStyle="None"
                                                        Font-Names="Century Gothic" Font-Size="XX-Small" DataKeyNames="id"
                                                        Width="100%" Style="margin-bottom: 0px" CssClass="grid">
                                                        <Columns>
                                                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" />
                                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                                           <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" />
                                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="pid" HeaderText="pid" />
                                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="Description" />
                                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="country" HeaderText="country" />
                                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="pack" HeaderText="pack" />
                                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="customer" HeaderText="customer" />
                                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="jobnumber" HeaderText="jobnumber" />
                                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="artworkdate" HeaderText="artworkdate" />
                                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="reprodate" HeaderText="reprodate" />
                                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="artworknumber" HeaderText="artworknumber" />
                                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="templateno" HeaderText="templateno" />
                                                             <asp:TemplateField>
                                                                <ItemTemplate>
```

<asp:Button Text="View" ID="Inkview" runat="server" OnClick="Inkview_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' ForeColor="white" BackColor="#FF6600" />

```
                                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                                 
                                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                                             <asp:TemplateField>
                                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                              <asp:Button Text="Edit" ID="lnkView1" runat="server" OnClick="Inkview_Click1"     ForeColor="white"  BackColor="#FF6600"/>
                                                         </ItemTemplate>
                                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                                
                                                        </Columns>
                                                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="green" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
                                                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                        <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003399" />
                                                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
                                                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#EDF6F6" />
                                                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0D4AC4" />
                                                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D6DFDF" />
                                                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#002876" />
  </asp:GridView>
                                                    <br />
     <div class="Pager" style="width: 100%"></div>
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
    <script src="ASPSnippets_Pager.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            GetCustomers(1);
        });
        $('body').on('click', '.Pager .page', function () {
            GetCustomers(parseInt($(this).attr('page')));
        });
        $('body').on('click', '.view', function () {
            $('[id*=hfId]').val($(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(1).html());
        });
        var i = 0;
        function GetCustomers(pageIndex) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default22.aspx/GetCustomers",
                data: '{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    $('[id$=gvDetails]').prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($('[id$=gvDetails]').find("tr:first"))).DataTable().destroy();
                    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
                    var xml = $(xmlDoc);
    
                    var customers = xml.find("job");
                    var row = $("[id$=gvDetails] tbody tr:last-child").eq(0).clone(true);
                    $("[id$=gvDetails] tbody tr").not($("[id$=gvDetails] tbody tr:first-child")).remove();
                    $.each(customers, function () {
                        $("td", row).eq(1).html($(this).find("id").text());
                        $("td", row).eq(2).html($(this).find("pid").text());
                        $("td", row).eq(3).html($(this).find("description").text());
                        $("td", row).eq(4).html($(this).find("country").text());
                        $("td", row).eq(5).html($(this).find("pack").text());
                        $("td", row).eq(6).html($(this).find("customer").text());
                        $("td", row).eq(7).html($(this).find("jobnumber").text());
                        $("td", row).eq(8).html($(this).find("artworkdate").text());
                        $("td", row).eq(9).html($(this).find("reprodate").text());
                        $("td", row).eq(10).html($(this).find("artworknumber").text());
                        $("td", row).eq(11).html($(this).find("templateno").text());
                        $("[id$=gvDetails]").append(row);
                        row = $("[id$=gvDetails] tbody tr:last-child").eq(0).clone(true);
                    });
                    $("[id$=gvDetails] tbody tr:first-child").remove();
                    if (i != 0) {
                        $('[id$=gvDetails]').DataTable({
                            "paging": false,
                            "info": false
                        });
                    } else {
                        $('[id$=gvDetails]')
                            .prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($('[id$=gvDetails]').find("tr:first")))
                            .DataTable({
                                "paging": false,
                                "info": false
                            });
                    }
                    i++;
                    var pager = xml.find("Pager");
                    $(".Pager").ASPSnippets_Pager({
                        ActiveCssClass: "current",
                        PagerCssClass: "pager",
                        PageIndex: parseInt(pager.find("PageIndex").text()),
                        PageSize: parseInt(pager.find("PageSize").text()),
                        RecordCount: parseInt(pager.find("RecordCount").text())
                    });
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        BindDummyRow();
    }
  

   

}
 private void BindDummyRow()
    {
        DataTable dummy = new DataTable();
        dummy.Columns.Add("id");
        dummy.Columns.Add("pid");
        dummy.Columns.Add("description");
        dummy.Columns.Add("Country");
        dummy.Columns.Add("pack");
        dummy.Columns.Add("customer");
        dummy.Columns.Add("jobnumber");
        dummy.Columns.Add("artworkdate");
        dummy.Columns.Add("reprodate");
        dummy.Columns.Add("artworknumber");
        dummy.Columns.Add("templateno");


        dummy.Rows.Add();
        gvDetails.DataSource = dummy;
        gvDetails.DataBind();
        //gvDetails.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
        //gvDetails.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
    }




    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetCustomers(int pageIndex)
    {
        string query = "[boj]";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageIndex", pageIndex);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageSize", PageSize);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecordCount", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        return GetData(cmd, pageIndex).GetXml();
    }

    private static DataSet GetData(SqlCommand cmd, int pageIndex)
    {
        string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    sda.Fill(ds, "job");
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Pager");
                    dt.Columns.Add("PageIndex");
                    dt.Columns.Add("PageSize");
                    dt.Columns.Add("RecordCount");
                    dt.Rows.Add();
                    dt.Rows[0]["PageIndex"] = pageIndex;
                    dt.Rows[0]["PageSize"] = PageSize;
                    dt.Rows[0]["RecordCount"] = cmd.Parameters["@RecordCount"].Value;
                    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
                    return ds;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    protected void Inkview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      int id = Convert.ToInt32(((Button)sender).CommandArgument);

        Session["DatakeyValue"] = id;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=NERE\\SQLEXPRESS01; Initial Catalog=kaging;Integrated Security=True;");
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand();
        cm.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cm.CommandText = "SELECT pid FROM job WHERE id=@id'";
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Session["DatakeyValue"]);
        Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(cm.ExecuteScalar());
        con.Close();

          }
```

////////////////////////////////////////

```
This is the stored procedure i  used(boj).

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[boj]
      @PageIndex INT = 1
      ,@PageSize INT = 15
      ,@RecordCount INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
      (
                  ORDER BY [id] ASC
      )AS RowNumber
      ,[id]
      ,[pid]    
      ,[description]
       ,[country]
      ,[pack]
      ,[customer]
      ,[jobnumber]
      ,[artworkdate]
      ,[reprodate]
      ,[artworknumber]
      ,[templateno]
      INTO #Results
      FROM [job]
      
      SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*)
      FROM #Results
            
      SELECT * FROM #Results
      WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1
      
      DROP TABLE #Results
END
GO
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////

I have tried the following,same error  - Input string was not in a correct format.

Int32.Parse(hiddenfield.value).

Convert.ToInt32(hiddenfield.value)

Please help

Comment: Is this for an ASP.NET Web Application?

Comment: What's the value in `hiddenfield.Value`?

Comment: Yes it is for an ASP.NET Web Application.The value of hiddenfield.Value is always an integer(id).I am trying to get the  cell value of a row (id )of a  gridview  then use it to select  other parameter.

Comment: Can you post further code to show how you are trying to retrieve the cell value?  What event are you using?  We need to understand how you are populating that controls value property.

Comment: `The value of hiddenfield.Value is always an integer(id)` The short answer is that is not true. Please share the actual value.

Comment: What we really need to see is how you are populating hfId.Value in the first instance.

Comment: I mean for  my project  the hiddenfield.Value is always an integer(id).The id value is always an integer for my project alone,not generally speaking  @mjwills.

Comment: I used jquery  pager  to populate my gridview in c#

Comment: OK.  And how are you assigning your ID to the HiddenField Value property?  Is it based on a row click or button click?

Comment: `I mean for my project the hiddenfield.Value is always an integer(id).` And I am saying that can't be true, if `Int32.Parse` doesn't work.

Comment: I assign id  based on button click on every row of the grid view

Comment: $('body').on('click', '.view', function () {
        $('[id*=hfId]').val($(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(1).html());
    });

Comment: it takes the column value which are the ids of all the rows located in the first column

Comment: please show more code to get a better context of your issue and can bring it a solution

Comment: the id is the primary key and it has identity column (int) @ mjwills

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to get your "id" from the GridView control.

As you are binding the data.  You can set the CommandArgument of the Button control in your ItemTemplate to the "id" of the record using the Eval function.

```
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button Text="View" ID="Inkview" runat="server" OnClick="Inkview_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' ForeColor="white" BackColor="#FF6600" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

This way you can dispense with the use of the HiddenField control and trying to set that.

You can then update your InkView_Click event to extract the "id" from the CommandArgument:

```
protected void Inkview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(((Button)sender).CommandArgument);

            Session["DatakeyValue"] = id;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=NERE\\SQLEXPRESS01; Initial Catalog=kaging;Integrated Security=True;");
            SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand();
            cm.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cm.CommandText = "SELECT pid FROM job WHERE id=@id'";
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Session["DatakeyValue"]);
            Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(cm.ExecuteScalar());
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Same Error ,System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: I think the issue lies in the Ajax request.  Are you calling a bind in there after you’ve retrieved the data?  With my example, if you use your Dummy Data object, create a new row in the DataTable and bind that DataTable to the GridView in the Page Load event, this works.

Comment: Hello Kev,Thanks for your help so far,i appreciate.The binding takes place inside Page Load event.I have updated my code above.That is the full code above.You can try it  and you get the same error.

Comment: Thanks.  I’ll take another look for you.

Comment: Do you see any data in the GridView when it has loaded?  Are you able to share a screenshot?